# Rpi Webrtc echo cancellation - aec

Tags: pi-3, webrtc, usb-audio, microphone, speakers

I am using [Rpi-Webrtc-streamer](https://github.com/kclyu/rpi-webrtc-streamer) for webrtc on raspberry pi with usb sound card connected to audio amplifier for speakers and electret microphone. I am able to run webrtc correctly but with issue of mic catching echo from speaker. I have tried to enable echo processing as provided by library but didn't work. Echo is not at all removed. In fact there are no change invoice quality by any of audio processing.

I have also tried using [this library](https://github.com/voice-engine/ec) for software echo cancellation but it is not working with webrtc streamer. Is there any way to work around the issue of echo as it is very important for us to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option that the AEC (Acoustic Echo Cancellation) you are trying to use is not capable of handling the echo tail in your system. I suggest to start by measuring the echo tail in your system. The following post will guide you how to measure the [echo tail](https://solicall.com/analyze-the-echo-path-yourself/).

Comment: so if i calculate my echo tail to be 200 ms, there is any way to reduce it via software?

Comment: No. In this case you should look for an echo cancellation software that supports  200ms.

Comment: I am using above webrtc library. How to make echo cancellation work before that? I cannot modify code of library right now. Is that possible?

Comment: webrtc is open source. You can download source code and modify it per your requirements. Please note that modifying the AEC engine is not a simple task.

Comment: What does AEC mean?

Comment: AEC stands for Acoustic Echo Cancellation